# How to build source files within Xcode project in a specific order

Tags: xcode, build

There's a lot of information about how to specify the build order for the targets. But there's no information about how to make the source files within a single project build in specific order.

For example I need main.m to be build last, yet Xcode builds if first. Is there any way to specify the build order for the source files?

Comment: Why do you need files to be built in a specific order?

Comment: Why wouldn't I :) I have a specific llvm processing step, which affects the compilation of .o modules. And it's necessary to compile the source files in the proper sequence in order for the linker to succeed.

Comment: I don't suppose you managed to get a solution to this?

Comment: nope I didn't. And I can't remember how I dealt with my original issue